# Selectively appending elements from a list to a new list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, yield

Using a loose definition of the word 'sequence' I have a list with over 2,000 elements (sequence numbers) and for each short sequence I want to append the highest number to a separate list. Here's a representative and simplified example of my data:

`# seqNums = ['01', '02', '01', '02', '03', '01', '01', '02', '03', '04', '01', '02', '03', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05']`

In this example I would want to append elements 1, 4, 5, 9, 12, and 17 to a new list to look like the below 'newSeqNums'.

`# newSeqNums = ['02', '03', '01', '04', '03', '05']`

I've tried many different things and the below code is the closet I can get to reading ahead in the list but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
seqNums = ['01', '02', '01', '02', '03', '01', '01', '02', '03', '04', '01', '02', '03', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
newSeqNums = []
def readAhead(seqNums):
    for item in seqNums:
        yield item
    yield None

items = readAhead(seqNums)
item = items.next()          # get first item

while item:
    nextItem = items.next()  # get next item
    if item < nextItem:
        pass
    else:
        newSeqNums.append(nextItem)
    item = items.next()

print newSeqNums
print len(newSeqNums)

'''
# output for above code
['01', '01']
2
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I had such a hard time with this but as usual (at least as far as it concerns me) the solution was simpler than I thought it would be, I tend to over-think things. So anyways, the below code gives me the solution that I want.

```
seqNums = ['01', '02', '01', '02', '03', '01', '01', '02', '03', '04', '01', '02', '03', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
newSeqNums = []
for i in range(len(seqNums)):
    if seqNums[i] == seqNums[-1]:
        newSeqNums.append(seqNums[-1])
    elif seqNums[i] < seqNums[i + 1]:
        pass
    else:
        newSeqNums.append(seqNums[i])
print newSeqNums


'''
# output for above code
['02', '03', '01', '04', '03', '05']
''''
```

Comment: Can the above solution be converted into a list comprehension?